# Call javascript from appended text (order cart)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Let's say that I'm building something like order cart.

I have one main page, and a lot of subpages.
On the subpages I have some specified product which user can add to the order by clicking on the button.

If the user click the button, javascript is called grabbing the name of the product and sending it AJAX to some PHP file which add this product name to some $_SESSION array.

If there's atleast one product in the cart, the FIXED div on the bottom of the screen appear. This div runs modal (bootstrap) and it contains all of the products which user had add to the order. Again I'm using here javascript + AJAX to determine click. If it's, there is a call to .php file which return STRING contains all the products. Then, this string is appended to the div inside this modal.

Content of this modal looks like:

'name_of_the_product', 'delete', 'id_from_session_array'
...
...

So I want allow the user to use DELETE option for any of his products in this list if he no longer want this product in the cart. I wrapped the delete text in some anchor and gave it class - let's say '.delete_from_cart'.

And now, when I'm trying to check in javascript if this element ('.delete_from_cart') has been clicked, nothing happens. 
Sample code for this looks like:

```
$('.delete_from_cart').click(function() {
   alert("foo");
});
```

No alert at all after clicking some .delete_from_cart div. However, in the code source all of this anchors has this class.

How to fix that? It seems like javascript doesnt see appended elements from ajax in this div. Any help?

Comment: any error in browser console ..? can you give us a demo fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you said that your modal is generated using an Ajax call, you will not be able to attach the click event to the element. You will need to use jQuerys on() method to bind the onclick.

```
$("#themodal").on( "click", ".delete_from_cart", function(){
 alert('it worked');
```

});

See on() method more details.
https://api.jquery.com/on/